# Crontab an alias which runs a specific virtualenv's Python interpreter, why doesn't work?

Tags: python, bash, macos, cron

Hello.

I'm trying to execute an asynchronous Django custom command by using MacOS cron jobs but nothing seems to work.

First, I tried to write a bash file that sources the virtualenv and then executes the manage.py with my custom command:

```
#!/bin/bash

source "/Users/airiefenix//Workspaces/ytsm_container/venv/bin/activate" && python /.../manage.py my_command
```

but I got

```
File "manage.py", line 17, in <module>
"Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and (...)
```

so source is not working on my bash script. I tried many methods, including replacing source with . (dot operator), splitting the script in two or more lines, etc. Apparently there's no way to activate a virtualenv from a bash script so I gave up and made an alias

```
$ alias python_ytsm="/Users/airiefenix/Workspace/ytsm_container/venv/bin/python3.6"
```

Running "python_ytsm /.../manage.py my_command" works perfectly but when I add it to the cron list:

```
$ crontab -e
```

Cron file:

```
01 * * * * python_ytsm "/Users/airiefenix/Workspace/ytsm_container/project/manage.py my_command"
```

Absolutely nothing happens. I already checked the cron jobs list with crontab -l and my script is there. I also added some other lines to the crontab file with basic commands such as "touch file.txt" or "echo 'hello' >> somefile.txt" and all those jobs are executing normally.

What's the problem? Is it with my alias? Is it with the "custom/virtualenv" Python interpreter? I'd love to give more details but MacOS is extremely scarce full while logging cron jobs.

I'm using MacOS Sierra, I know cron is supposedly deprecated but to me it's much easier than using launchdl so unless I definitely can't make it work through cron I'd like to keep using it. Thanks.

Comment: `exec >>/tmp/cron.log 2>&1; PS4=':$LINENO'; set -x` is a good place to start; that way you'll get logs in `/tmp/cron.log`, hopefully with a more useful error message.

Comment: BTW, note that the default value of `SHELL` used by cron is `/bin/sh`, not `bash`. That means that you're only guaranteed POSIX-baseline syntax -- meaning `.` rather than `source`, for instance. (I'm not offhand sure which `/bin/sh` is default on Sierra, so I don't know which extensions are and aren't there -- but the safe thing is to assume that you'll have only what the POSIX sh standard guarantees unless you explicitly run a more capable shell).

Comment: And aliases aren't **ever** available in crontab. Never have been.

Comment: BTW, the claim that virtualenvs don't work in cron jobs is itself not supported by the evidence.

Comment: If aliases have been never allowed how do I run a Python script using the Python interpreter from a virtualenv?

Comment: virtualenvs don't use/need/require aliases -- they use environment variables and shell functions to work.

Comment: `python_ytsm() { /Users/airiefenix/Workspace/ytsm_container/project/manage.py my_command "$@"; }`, by the way, is a function equivalent to your alias. Of course, you still need to get it defined in the shell you're invoking from crontab, but at least you don't need to use the nonstandard `shopt` command to make it be recognized once it's been sourced into your shell.

Comment: Really, though, I'd suggest editing your crontab such that the job starts with the prefix I gave in the first line of this answer, and [edit]ing the question based on the logs created.

Answer (score 2):

Aliases are disabled by default in noninteractive shells, so even if you source a file that defines them, they won't be honored. Moreover, dotfiles aren't sourced on noninteractive shell startup, so your `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, `.profile`, or another place where you might have defined the alias won't be evaluated when a command is called from cron.

If you **really** want an alias, consider:

```
# instruct cron to use bash as your shell
SHELL=/bin/bash

# . "$HOME/.bashrc" <- assumes that your .bashrc defines the alias python_ytsm
# shopt -s expand_aliases <- turns aliases on; off-by-default in noninteractive context
# ...and then your regular command.
01 * * * * . "$HOME/.bashrc" && shopt -s expand_aliases && python_ytsm "/Users/airiefenix/Workspace/ytsm_container/project/manage.py my_command"
```

but it's much better practice not to rely on them.